# Parallel calls to web service vs single call with loop in service

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, rest, webservice-client

My UI(AngularJS) provides a REST service(Java Spring) with a list of objects(of the same type), say, `Person`. The service makes a single call to persist each `Person`.
Is it better that

> 1) The service deal with a single `Person` at a time and the UI make parallel service calls.

OR

> 2) The UI send a list of Persons and the service persists them in a loop?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think the former is the more efficient solution out of the two.

Comment: Why do you think that? Let's say I wanted to give you candy. Would you rather that I gave you the candy one at a time with both hands, or give you the whole bag at once?

Comment: The UI would not have to wait for long. Shorter clearer service layer code.

Comment: The service layer will not have to deal with partial failures related to the validation of the `Person` object.

Comment: Let's say you've got 100 users sending 10 persons to the server. Suddenly you have 1000 connections to the server instead of 100. Can your server handle it? Let's say persisting one of the Persons fails. Is that okay, or do you want to roll back the whole transaction so that either all are saved or nothing is?

Comment: We will have around 4000 users/day each sending a max of 3 Persons. We dont rollback the whole transaction but we need to inform the UI persistence of which person failed/succeeded.

Comment: I'm just providing you with something to think about. Making parallel calls would never fly (or would require a bigger effort) in a more complex situation, even if it may work for your particular use case here.